# IT Security & Programming Community

Tags: security

Do you know about any community/forums/whatever that focuses on IT Security and programming related to it. Something like [this](http://www.hackforums.net/) but without all the *"OMG!1! LOLZ! Tezt my h3llo world!!!!1!111!!"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

For the programming part, I think that this would be a good place for it.